# The release allows generation of archived apks

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

Today when i tried to update my app, i got this warning message
**"The release allows generation of archived apks"**.

Do you advise me to ignore this warning or canceling **"Store Archive"** feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application can be archived by users to save space. You can make it inactive. Have you seen? [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/03/freeing-up-60-of-storage-for-apps.html)!

```
android {
    bundle {
        storeArchive {
            enable = false
        }
    }
}
```